# systemd activates unit ran by timer upon changing the OnCalendar directive

Tags: debian, systemd, services, systemd-timer

I have a systemd timer setup with this OnCalendar value:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 05:35:00
```

Upon changing it to

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 06:35:00
```

And running `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the configratuion the .service unit file ran by the timer activated(the script started).
The .service file before running `daemon-reload`:

```
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-02-18 05:35:08 EET; 5h 1min ago
```

The .service file after running `daemon-reload`

```
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-02-18 10:37:10 EET; 4s ago
```

The .timer unit before running `daemon-reload`

```
Trigger: Wed 2020-02-19 05:35:00 EET; 18h left
```

After:

```
Trigger: Wed 2020-02-19 06:35:00 EET; 19h left
```

The trigger has the correct timestamp on when it should run next but it the service unit started when i ran daemon-reload. This is could be a critical issue if you have backups or logrotate that is ran by a timer.

Comment: I realize this is a bit late. I think that if you have persistent=true set the timer will run because it thinks that it missed the earlier OnCalendar date that you had set.